# AnyLogic mean waiting time in queue

Tags: queue, histogram, anylogic

I would like to get the mean waiting time of each unit spending in my queue of every hour. (so betweeen 7-8 am for example 4 minutes, 8-9 10 minutes and so on). Thats my current queue with my timemeasure Is there a way to do so?

[image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a normal dataset and call it *datasetHourly*. Deactivate the option *Use time as horizontal value*. This is where we will store your hourly data.

Creat a cyclic event and set the trigger to cyclic, once every hour.

This cyclic event will get the current mean of your time measurement ( waiting time + service time in your example) and save this single value in the extra dataset.
Also we have to clear the dataset that is integrated into the *timeMeasurementEnd*, in order to get clean statistics again for the next hour interval.

```java
datasetHourly.add(time(HOUR),timeMeasureEnd.dataset.getYMean());
timeMeasureEnd.dataset.reset();
```

[image: time measurement]

You can now visualise the hourly development by adding the *hourlyDataset* to a normal plot.